# Parsing and formatting var_export() string

Tags: performance, php, parsing, formatting

I have this script to format var_export's result string. The information in the output is good, but I need know if the code performance is good or if it can be improved.

https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/biDk

```
<?php
#Variable:

$Test                            = [];
$Test['Check1']                  = null;
$Test['Check2']                  = [];
$Test['Check2']['int']           = 20;
$Test['Check2']['float']         = 20.35;
$Test['Check2']['string']        = 'Hello World';
$Test['Check2']['bolean']        = true;
$Test['Check2']['array']         = [];
$Test['Check2']['array']['data'] = 'Array Text';
class Example {
    function foo_function() {
        return "Hello World! Object";
    }
}
$var_object                         = new Example;
$Test['Check2']['array']['object']  = $var_object;
$Test['Check2']['array']['object2'] = $var_object->foo_function();

#Script Type:
function myGetType($var) {
    if (is_null($var) OR $var == 'null' OR $var == 'NULL') {
        return "(NULL)";
    }

    if (is_array($var)) {
        return "array";
    }

    if (in_array($var, array("true", "false"), true)) {
        return "boolean";
    }

    if ((int) $var == $var && is_numeric($var)) {
        return "integer" . '(' . strlen($var) . ')';
    }

    if ((float) $var == $var && is_numeric($var)) {
        return "float" . '(' . strlen($var) . ')';
    }

    if (is_object($var)) {
        return "object";
    }

    if (is_resource($var)) {
        return "resource";
    }

    if (is_string($var)) {
        return "string" . '(' . strlen($var) . ')';
    }

    return "unknown";
}

#Script Analisis:
function VarExportFormat($Var) {
    $textvar    = '';
    $textvar    = var_export($Var, true);
    $textvar    = preg_replace("/^([ ]*)(.*)/m", '$1$1$2', $textvar);
    $textvarArr = preg_split("/\r\n|\n|\r/", $textvar);
    # Analisis del tipo.
    foreach ($textvarArr as $key => $value) {
        preg_match('~=>\\s(.*?),~', $value, $newvalue);
        if (!empty($newvalue)) {
            $newvalue[1]      = str_replace("'", "", $newvalue[1]);
            $typeval          = myGetType($newvalue[1]);
            $value            = str_replace("=> ", "=> " . $typeval . ': ', $value);
            $textvarArr[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    $textvarArr = preg_replace(["/\s*array\s\($/", "/\)(,)?$/", "/\s=>\s$/"], [NULL, ']$1', ' => array ['], $textvarArr);
    $textvar    = join(PHP_EOL, array_filter(["array ["] + $textvarArr));
    if (substr($textvar, -1) == '[') {
        $textvar = str_replace("[", "[]", $textvar);
    }
    $textvar = str_replace("__set_state", "__set_state(object)", $textvar);

    $textvar = highlight_string("<?php \n#output of Variable:\n" . $textvar . ";\n?>", true);
    return $textvar;
}

echo VarExportFormat($Test);
```

Comment: `(string)$string == $string` can be a replacement aswell for `is_string()`, same trick you did with int and floats..

Comment: `(object)$var == $var` and  `(array)$var == $var`  can also works aswell to replace is_object and is_array but performance is more depending on the object or array size and or PHP version, this trick does not scale that that well as the int, string types..  Might be interesting to test with?

Comment: Using [token_get_all()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) -> *"token_get_all() parses the given source string into PHP language tokens using the Zend engine's lexical scanner. "* seams to be making much more sense.. As you are making a parser/lexer color based syntax highlighter as `var_export()` returns parseable PHP...

Comment: @Raymond please do not abuse comments and break SE page design.  If you want to provide a review, then post an answer.  Comments should be used to request clarifications.  Please remove all of your comments after posting your answer.

Comment: *" Please remove all of your comments after posting your answer."* @mickmackusa not going to place a answer/review as mine comments are heavy based on PHP version... Also comments are meant to possibly provide extra information where [possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)..   -> *"Comments exist so that users can talk about questions and answers without posting new answers that do not make an attempt to answer the question asked. Comments are often used to ask for clarification on, **suggest corrections to**, and provide meta-information about posts. "*

Comment: I need to clarify that the main variable result of var_export is a string and therefore I cannot use is_string (), is_float, is_integer, because is_string will always be valid, I must evaluate if the string can be converted to the other types to validate them so use (int) (float) etc, and then I make the comparison == (without type)

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script is like a `var_export()`-`var_dump()` hybrid with flare (I've not come across `highlight_string()` before -- pretty cool).

1. I ran some more tests with a few samples that I had laying around and noticed that your code is having some difficulties accessing the written "resource" branch.  I tested with `fopen($filename, 'r')`; the `var_export()` evaluation of a resource is `NULL` and `var_dump()` returns `resource(5) of type (stream)`.  Because your script is founded on `var_export()`, it will fail to dignify the `resource` type data, I think you [sh/c]ould remove that from your battery of checks.
2. Miscellaneous gotchas include:

   ```
   ['a => key' => 'something']
   ```

   and

   ```
   ['multiline' => 'line1
   line2']
   ```

   These will break your regex-based parsing -- of course, the former is going to be a much less common occurrence versus the latter.
3. You can safely remove some useless declarations:

   - `$Test = [];` and `$textvar = '';`
4. As a general rule, I prefer to never use `OR` or `AND` in my conditional statements as a matter of consistency and as a means to avoid fringe precedence issues.
5. `preg_replace("/^([ ]*)(.*)/m", '$1$1$2', $textvar);` This pattern/function is over-performing.  It doesn't make any sense to pick up the second capture group, just to put it back down unaltered.  In fact, there is no need for capture groups or character classes for this task.  I will also recommend that you use a consistent pattern delimiter for all patterns in your script. A tilde is a good/popular choice because it shouldn't interfere with any of your patterns and will help to prevent any accidental typos and escaping problems elsewhere.  To double the leading whitespace on each line, just use this (there's no use doubling zero whitespaces, so match one-or-more with `+`):

   ```
   preg_replace('~^ +~m', '$0$0', $textvar);
   ```
6. `$textvarArr = preg_split("/\r\n|\n|\r/", $textvar)` is more succinctly written as:

   ```
   $textvarArr = preg_split("~\R~", $textvar)
   ```
7. Whenever I see `preg_match()` called inside of a loop so that replacement actions can be performed, this is a classic indicator that `preg_replace_callback()` should be called.

   ```
   $textvarArr = preg_split("~\R~", $textvar);
   foreach ($textvarArr as $key => $value) {
       preg_match('~=>\\s(.*?),~', $value, $newvalue);
       if (!empty($newvalue)) {
           $newvalue[1]      = str_replace("'", "", $newvalue[1]);
           $typeval          = myGetType($newvalue[1]);
           $value            = str_replace("=> ", "=> " . $typeval . ': ', $value);
           $textvarArr[$key] = $value;
       }
   }
   ```

   can become:

   ```
   $textvar = preg_replace_callback(
       "~ => \K\V+(?=,)~", 
       function ($m) {
           return myGetType(str_replace("'", "", $m[0])) . ": {$m[0]}";
       },
       $textvar
   );
   // then proceed with something like...
   $textvarArr = preg_replace(["/\s*array\s\($/", "/\)(,)?$/", "/\s=>\s$/"], [NULL, ']$1', ' => array ['], preg_split("~\R~", $textvar));
   ```
8. I've got to say that this looks a little dangerous...

   ```
   if (substr($textvar, -1) == '[') {
       $textvar = str_replace("[", "[]", $textvar);
   }
   ```

   I mean, you are checking the final character, then doing a full text scan and replace operation.  This deserves a bit of double-checking.  Don't you only mean to close the final square brace? Maybe...

   ```
   if (substr($textvar, -1) == '[') {
       $textvar .= "]";
   }
   ```

I didn't get a chance to properly review (but it could probably use a little polish/simplifying):

```
$textvarArr = preg_replace(["/\s*array\s\($/", "/\)(,)?$/", "/\s=>\s$/"], [NULL, ']$1', ' => array ['], preg_split("~\R~", $textvar));
$textvar    = join(PHP_EOL, array_filter(["array ["] + $textvarArr));
```

I ran our outputs on a diffchecker program to be sure that my script returns the exact same output as yours.

Overall, an interesting exercise, good job.

Comment: I have no idea the ramifications of rebuilding this script on that function.  I have only ever seen that function used on this site (never anywhere else in the SE network).  I am happy for you to demonstrate.

Comment: I don't see `resource` on that list either.

Comment: I need to clarify that the main variable result of var_export is a string and therefore I cannot use is_string (), is_float, is_integer, because is_string will always be valid, I must evaluate if the string can be converted to the other types to validate them so use (int) (float) etc, and then I make the comparison == (without type)

Comment: the link you provided not have your personalized code.

Comment: 1. It is correct, I will do more testing and verify if I can give you the scope for resources.
2. In the case what would you recommend to do?

Comment: 3. They are declarations for tests, since I imagined that they would ask me for a functional example, I can declare an array with a simpler declaration, but some new users would not fully understand it.
4. Replace them in the myGetType conditionals.

Comment: 5. I think duplicate blanks are to keep an indented to 4 spaces.
6. Thank you I will take it into account and try it.
7. Thank you I will take it into account and try it.

Comment: 8. It happens that if the past value is a null variable, it does not close the square bracked. and that's why I have to do a verification and close it manually, I didn't find another solution.

Comment: in your comment 7. `$textvarArr = preg_replace(["/\s*array\s\($/", "/\)(,)?$/", "/\s=>\s$/"], [NULL, ']$1', ' => array ['], preg_split("~\R~", $textvar));` trown error: preg_split() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Comment: Notice in my snippet at #7, I am using the string `$textvar` in `preg_replace_callback()`, its output, and the `preg_split()` call -- the data stays as a string until it is split into an array on the last line. You may have a typo with `Arr`.

Comment: you can add more about my question of every section you comment...

Comment: i have make other post result of it... if you can help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58458584/something-wrong-with-regular-expressions?noredirect=1#comment103319154_58458584

Comment: Gotta sleep.  Maybe tomorrow.

Comment: no problem i wait for you :)

Comment: i have meet finish the script, but i dont know if is the best way to get the output of data, can you check my Link sandbox.